# Angular creating named instances of providers

Tags: angular, factory, angular-providers, angular-factory

In Angular I have a service to access a cache. The service roughly works like this (but with a lot more asynchronous behavior).

```ts
@Injectable()
export class Cache {

  cache : CacheTable;

  constructor(
    protected name : string
  ) {
    this.cache = this.getTable(name);
  }

  put(id:string, data:any):void { this.cache.put(id, data); }
  get(id:string):any { return this.cache.get(id); }

  getTable(name : string) : CacheTable;

}
```

Now I have a number of services like `UserService` that would like to have a `Cache` corresponding to `new Cache('user');`. Another service named `ImageService` should work with an instance of `Cache` corresponding to `new Cache('image');`

For this I would like to create a Factory to provide these:

```ts
// file: custom-caches.ts

import { Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { Cache } from '../cache/cache';

export let userCache : Provider = {
  provide: Cache,
  useFactory: () => new Cache('user')
};

export let imageCache : Provider = {
  provide: Cache,
  useFactory: () => new Cache('image')
};
```

How would I go about registering and using each of these services? As far as I can tell they're all registered as '`Cache`'.

```ts
// file: my.module.ts

@NgModule({
  providers: [userCache, imageCache]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

(This relates to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867926/provider-constructor-properly-resolving-custom-provider))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @ghetolay I used `InjectionToken` and was able to successfully create multiple named providers as factoried instances:

```ts
// file: custom-caches.ts

import { Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { Cache } from '../cache/cache';

export const UserCache = new InjectionToken('userCache');

export let userCacheProvider : Provider = {
  provide: UserCache,
  useFactory: () => new Cache('user')
};

export const ImageCache = new InjectionToken('imageCache');

export let imageCacheProvider : Provider = {
  provide: ImageCache,
  useFactory: () => new Cache('image')
};
```

_

```ts
// file: my.module.ts

@NgModule({
  providers: [userCacheProvider, imageCacheProvider]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

_

```ts
// file : UserService

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(UserCache) private cache : Cache
  ) {}
}
```

`UserCache` and `ImageCache` are now tokens for these provider instances.